# In Bash, Why `then` is needed in the conditional constructs?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, syntax

The conditional construct of `if` command looks like this:

```
if TEST-COMMANDS; then
    CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS;
[elif MORE-TEST-COMMANDS; then
  MORE-CONSEQUENTS;]
[else ALTERNATE-CONSEQUENTS;]
fi
```

And the loop construct of `while` command looks like this:

```
while TEST-COMMANDS; do CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS; done
```

I was wondering why `then` is needed in `if` command but not in `while` command? Why couldn't it be ommited?

Comment: Because the syntax of the language says it is needed? The same way the syntax says `do` is needed in a `while` loop? How would you tell where the test commands and body commands started otherwise?

Comment: because a while loop's `do` is basically the same as the if test's `then`. It signifies the end of an argument list and beginning of the body of the if/while. Consider them the equivalent of C's `{`

Comment: iMHO - The only relevant (not opinion based) answer could be: **because the syntax of the bash wanted it**.

Comment: @jm666 the syntax of ancient sh, from which bash copied, is more likely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`do` in the `while` syntax serves a similar purpose to `then` in the `if` syntax.  They both signify the start of the body of the statement - differentiating it from the condition part of the statement.

The [if conditional statement](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07) is a compound statement in the shell.  The `if` & `then` sections of the statement are executed as two parts, the `then` section is only invoked if the `if` section ends with an exit status of `0`.  Both sections may contain multiple statements; therefore, a semi-colon alone is insufficient to separate these sections.

Comment: The `;` (a command/expression-break) is sufficient to "differentiat[e] it from the condition part". The reasoning given for *requiring* `then` is dubious.

Comment: @user2864740 no, it's not. `if true; true; false; then echo hi; else echo bye; fi` is a valid expression. How does bash know where the condition ends? `then`.

Comment: @user2864740 No it isn't. The condition can be multiple commands: `if var=$(mycmd); test -n "$var"; then true; fi`. This is very useful in loops. They could have added a special case disallowing this for `if` statements so you could avoid the `then`, but consistency is a good thing in grammars.

Comment: Put another way: the semicolon is a *command* terminator, just as it is everywhere else, not a *condition* terminator. `then` is the *condition* terminator.

Comment: This link might be slightly more useful than that TLDP link. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07

Comment: @chepner invoking the SRP? I like it.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments.  I will update the answer and choose a more appropriate reference.

Answer (score 1):

Like @shibley is saying in his answer, the `do` and `then` words are used to indicate the beginning of the block of actions to perform.

I have done some research and could not find the *historical* reasons, so I am going to guess the *logical* ones. It might be too subjective, so do not hesitate to comment your impressions below.

The bash syntax is quite "symmetrical": Whenever you have an `case` you finish it with `esac`. Also, it was designed in a very human way, so it is easily understandable.

That said, if you are in a `while` loop, it means that you are going to *do* something while a condition is true. Then, when it is not true anymore you are *done*.
However, in an `if` condition, you are saying that if something happens, *then*  something needs to be executed.

In short: `do` and `then` are human-readable ways to indicate the same, that is, the beginning of a block of commands to be performed upon a `while` or `if` condition.